# Help rearranging the formula $y^2+2xyz=1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need help rearranging this equation.

$$y^2+2xyz=1$$

How can I rearrange to solve for $x$?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you mean to solve for $x$, begin by moving $y^2$ to the right:

$$y^2 + 2xyz = 1 \implies y^2 - y^2 + 2xyz = 1 - y^2 \implies 2xyz = 1 - y^2$$

Next, divide by $2yz$, assuming that this quantity is non-zero:

$$x = \frac{2xyz}{2yz} = \frac{1 - y^2}{2yz}$$

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}
\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad y^2+2xyz&=1\\\\
2xyz&=1-y^2\\\\
x\cdot(2yz)&=1-y^2\\\\
x&=\frac{1-y^2}{2yz} &\small(\text{assuming }y,z\neq 0)
\end{align}$$